# Ubuntu VPS - email and webserver

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, dovecot

I have a VPS based on Ubuntu, it has installed whole LAMP, everything needed for a web server and it works perfectly, but I'm still not able to configure it as a mail server....
I have configured MX record for my domain mail.mydomain.com and this part is OK, I also installed Postfix, Dovecot and Roundcube, configured it using this tutorial: http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Mail_Server_setup

And after hours of configuring it doesn't work. I have experience with Linux and web hosting, but I successfully configured mail server once in past on Debian 6, and that with help from there.

When I try to send email to me my gmail says:

```
Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain mydomain.com by dc147738a1117e4c12273.mydomain.com. [MY_SERVER_IP].

The error that the other server returned was:
554 5.7.1 <xzero@mydomain.com>: Relay access denied
```

Also I have Webmin control panel which works perfectly, how to configure postfix and dovecot from there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would check: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_relay_restrictions If you still need help, please post a filtered copy of your /etc/postfix/main.cf config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by searching for solution over the web, and found it:

```
sudo tasksel install mail-server
```

One simple command, which fixed my headache, instead of numerous tries with 20+ commands and config file edits.

I'm just don't sure how to read emails with roundcube instead of using Webmin Read User Email, and how to have multiple email accounts.

SOURCE: https://askubuntu.com/questions/51887/how-to-set-up-a-mail-server-correctly?rq=1